# Spark code to write to a Kafka compacted topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

Does anyone know if it's possible to call `writeStream` to a Kafka topic, where the topic that gets created is a compacted topic?  The code below creates a Kafka topic,  but the options passed are ignored.

```
    StreamingQuery query = ds
            .writeStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092"))
            .option("topic", "myTopic")
            .option("cleanup.policy", "compact")
            .option("min.insync.replicas", 1)
            .option("segment.bytes", 4096)
            .option("delete.retention.ms", 100)
            .option("min.compaction.lag.ms", 0)
            .option("min.cleanable.dirty.ratio", 0.01)
            .start();
```

Comment: It's recommended to create your topic ahead of time... Even if this were possible, you left off the partition number and replication factor

Answer (score 1):

Spark Structure Streaming, when calls `writeStream` with kafka format under the hood uses KafkaProducer.

If on the broker side `auto.create.topics.enable` has `true` as a value (what is be default), 
when KafkaProducer fetches metadata new topic is created by the broker.

KafkaProducer doesn't pass any *topic's properties*. 
Broker uses default once (ex. `default.replication.factor`, `num.partitions`, `log.cleanup.policy`) to create topic.

You can't pass topic creation properties through KafkaProducer.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation also, use `kafka` prefix with producer or consumer properties.

> Kafka’s own configurations can be set via DataStreamReader.option with
>   kafka. prefix.

Example:

```
stream.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","host:port")
```

Also, you can pass only producer or consumer level properties in the `.options`. If you need any topic level configuration to be set, you need to use the broker config and that can't be set through spark streaming code, that is fetched from the default configuration.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations

Comment: your answer was wrong. After I've added mine, you have just copy it (even giving a source).

Comment: broker configs can't be passed to the Streaming Context, only producer and consumer ones

Comment: @cricket_007 : that's what I also mentioned "only producer or consumer level properties" not the broker properties

Comment: Maybe it's not clear when you wrote "you need to use the broker config", then

Comment: @cricket_007 : no worries, have updated it with more clear words

Comment: Still "broker config" and "topic configs" are different things entirely